# "this" in c# constructor?

Tags: c#

When referenced in the constructor, does the keyword this refer to the instance of the class being created?

For instance, I have a list of all instances of a certain class.  If I put
   MyList.Add(this);
at the end of the constructor, will that add the newly created class?

Comment: Out of interest if you are questioning this what other things did you think it might mean?

Comment: Also a class adding itself to a list in a constructor seems weird.  It would mean you have a class that contains a list with itself in it.  Bends my mind a little.

Comment: @BenRobinson The list doesn't necessarily have to be in the class itself (static, argument, etc). But yes, it does seem a bit odd.

Comment: @Rob either of those suggestions seems pretty odd too

Comment: @BenRobinson: That is not what it means. It means that the class is adding *a reference* to itself to a list that it contains *a reference* to. Imagine that you are the instance. You write your name on a piece of paper. You stick that piece of paper into a three-ring binder named "my notes". You write "my notes" on a piece of paper and put that in your pocket. Nothing weird about that. It's not *you* that is in the binder, it's just your name. It's not *the binder* that's in your pocket, it's just a piece of paper with the name of the binder on it in your pocket. Think in references.

Comment: @EricLippert yes i did understand that already. It wasn't the cyclic reference that was bending my mind. It was why you would do such a thing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes `this` refers to the current instance in the constructor just like in every other instance method.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it does.

Note that you are potentially exposing a partially-initialized instance of your class, [which can be a bad idea](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/09/02/don-t-let-this-get-away.aspx).

Comment: As SLaks said, it is important to note the security issues of exposing `this` in this manner

Answer (score 1):

Yes this refers current instance in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

`this` always refers to the current instance, 
you can use `this` as a pointer to the instance